# Datalist not functioning correctly on iOS Chrome

Tags: html, ios, google-chrome, datalist

As far as I know, ios Chrome is the only browser where my datalist is doing this. Any other browser or device combination seems to work. I know there used to be support issues for datalists but not seeing anything recent that explains the issue I am having. The datalist only does this when the input box receives focus.

[image: Image of the bug]

```html
<div>
  <label></label>
  <input id="plist" class="form-control" type="text" list="p" name="p" value="A">
  <datalist id="p">
    <option>S</option>
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
    <option>C</option>
    <option>D</option>
    <option>Aggron</option>
    <option>E</option>
    <option>F</option>
  </datalist>
</div>
```

Comment: https://www.stadiumgaming.gg/new-rank-checker to see it live.

Comment: You may need to create a [polyfill](https://github.com/thgreasi/datalist-polyfill) for your data list. Because as you said earlier, the data list is not supported in earlier browser versions.

Comment: But I’m using the latest version of chrome for iOS. Not a ten year old browser.

Answer (score 0):

IOS requires the value property

```
<div>
  <label></label>
  <input id="plist" class="form-control" type="text" list="p" name="p" value="A">
   <datalist id="p">
    <option value="S">S</option>
    ...
    </datalist>
</div>
```